# How to know what type of instance is used when executing a particular AWS lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

Is there a way to figure out what type of underlying instance is used for running an AWS lambda function? (c6i.large , c6i.2xlarge, t4g.micro etc.)

Comment: The underlying host is completely hidden from the function. There is no way to know what the hardware is, nor is it necessarily running on an EC2 instance that is of a type shared with users.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to know this?

Comment: AWS Lambda uses containers, not EC2 instances. You might find this interesting: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)

Comment: Actually, not containers, rather MicroVMs with an open source solution called Firecracker  https://firecracker-microvm.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The underlying infra in opaque by design. Probably the closest thing you can do is access to the function's memory size via the environment variable `AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_MEMORY_SIZE`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html